# Run-time error 1004 when running a Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get a macro to loop through the worksheets in an Excel document. I have never used VisualBasic before, so naturally, I have hit a wall.

```
Sub DoSheets()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
    Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Activate
        Call WeekUpdate
        ws.Cells(1, 1) = 1
    Next

    starting_ws.Activate

End Sub
```

Here is the code I am calling. It works on it's own when I run it through each worksheet one at a time, but this takes a very long time. Hence why I am trying to get the loop above to work.

```
Sub WeekUpdate()
    '
    ' WeekUpdate Macro
    ' Update the week for Wait Vs Price
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+J
    '
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
                            "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Year]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
                            "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Qtr]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
                            "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Period]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
                            "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Week]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
                                                                                               "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Week].&[2016015]")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
                            "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Date]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields( _
                            "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Year]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields( _
                            "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Qtr]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields( _
                            "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Period]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields( _
                            "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Week]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
                                                                                               "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Week].&[2017015]")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields( _
                            "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Date]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
End Sub
```

Comment: on which line is error? And do you have the pivottable in every sheet? By the same name etc?

Comment: Anything that works off `ActiveSheet` and requires you to `Activate` something, will be slow. Also consider pulling `PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields` and `PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields` into their own local object variable, instead of re-dereferencing the same objects over and over and over for every instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is good for a beginner, it just needs a few tweaks:

1. No need to use the `Call` keyword or activate `ws`.
2. You'll need to pass the relevant worksheet as an argument to `WeekUpdate`. Notice you don't need the brackets once you've dropped the `Call`:

---

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    WeekUpdate ws
    ws.Cells(1, 1) = 1
Next
```

---

3. Change the signature of your `WeekUpdate` sub to accept that worksheet parameter
4. change all `ActiveSheet` to `ws`:

---

```
Sub WeekUpdate(ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    '
    ' WeekUpdate Macro
    ' Update the week for Wait Vs Price
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+J
    '
    ws.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
                   "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Year]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
    ws.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
                   "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Qtr]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
    '... etc
```

---

**Update**

Even better. As suggested in the comments, For the `WeekUpdate` sub to be usable on its own still e.g. with the keyboard shortcut, use the following:

```
 Sub WeekUpdate(Optional ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    '
    ' WeekUpdate Macro
    ' Update the week for Wait Vs Price
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+J
    '
    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet

    ws.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
                   "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Year]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
    ws.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields( _
                   "[Date].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Qtr]").VisibleItemsList = Array("")
    '... etc
```

Comment: Note that this effectively makes the macro no longer executable with its assigned shortcut. A better change would take an `Optional ByVal ws As Worksheet` parameter, and `If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet`, to preserve the current behavior and keep the macro working with Ctrl+Shift+J.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Good point, I pretty much never assign keyboard shortcuts so I was oblivious to that one!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing 'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets' with 'ActiveWorkbook.worksheets' and also try adding 'Next WS' versus just 'next'

Comment: Both of those suggestions will have no effect in this instance (and actually the former is a *bad idea*)

Comment: Per VBA language specifications, `Next` can very well sit on its own, and specifying what identifier it's for, makes no difference whatsoever - other than making bulky code even bulkier, especially in a non-nested loop structure.